# How to get google map marker id when click the marker?

Tags: javascript

How I can get maker ID when click it?

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
var locationTitle=marker;
infowindow.setContent(contentString);
infowindow.open(map, marker);});
```

Comment: A [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) has no `id`. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {               
  window.location = "www.cickstart.com/" + marker.id;
});
```